# Flask webapp deployed on IIS does not serve network folder files

Tags: python, flask, iis-8

Firstly this is my debut query on stack overflow , hope i have maintained the required protocols.

Have a flask app running on Windows 2012.
I have a simple flask app which serves local and network files (.pdf,.csv). When i run the flask app thru' terminal it is able to serve both Local and network files when the embedded url is clicked .The files open in a new tab.

But when i launch it thru IIS, it is only able to serve local files and throws access denied messages[Error 13] whenever the network file url is clicked
Have been breaking my head over it.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you pls tell us if there's any restriction on hit the network file? I mean that if you can access the file through the url in the browser directly.

Comment: Hi Wang, there seems to be no restriction , if i run the flask app using terminal and then i call the endpoint url by pasting it in the browser , the file gets displayed , but when i add the same end point to the page invoked by IIS , it throws this access denied error. eg ; thru terminal is add i have this url : 192.xxx.xxx.xx:5000/return-files/R42424 which will display me the pdf( from network folder), from the iis i have the same url ( but instead of IP , i have DNS resolved host name) but it gives me Winerror

Comment: Maybe this document can help you.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: You may try to set ACL or change the application pool identity

Comment: Try to changing the [identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/understanding-identities) to Network Service https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcigw.png

Comment: All new IIS users must learn the differences first, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: Sorry for the much delayed answer , was stuck in another project , did try to change to Network Service, but the issue remains

Answer (score 0):

Trying to change the identity to Network Service.

[image]